# Humidistat with Foggy Wet Windows

Tags: hvac

I just replaced my filter, open the damper, put it on low humidity, about -20 outside and still the windows are dripping wet. The line looks clear but I don't think I should mess with the little box/fan/motor(?) Maybe I need to call the guy ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A better explanation of what you have and what  problems you are trying to fix is necessary.  Trying to decipher your explanation is impossible without a better explanation. If water on your windows is your problem, you may need a dehumidifier.